# Given a sample of time-series spatial data, how do I determine the minimum number of spatial points that is statistically similar to the large set?

Tags: sampling, matlab, dataset, spatial

I have a solar irradience data set that was generated from 45 independent stations within a square mile. The stations are more or less regularly spaced in a grid. The data are 1Hz and are all time-synced (in theory). Having all 45 stations gives us a good idea of what the sunlight is doing over this square mile for each second of the 550 days of data that we have (20Gb). However, photovoltaic developers don't want to spend money on 45 stations to measure solar irradience when they can spend money on X stations over Y area and determine the solar variability. The question is what are X and Y? Since maintaining the solar variability is necessary, the area is part of the equation.

Solar variability refers to changes in measured solar irradience over space and time. Clear and overcast days are not variable whereas partly cloudy days can generate larges spikes in irradience values. The spikes in irradience throughout the day are quantified as having high "solar variability". For PV power plants the spikes result in voltage changes on transmission lines, something utilities do not like. For more information see:

http://energy.sandia.gov/wp/wp-content/gallery/uploads/Stein_ASES_2012_VI_paper_SAND2012-2088C1.pdf

I wrote a Matlab program to tackle this problem. First, I used 10 seconds of the full data set and calculated the mean and StdDev for each second using all 45 stations. (Once the algorithm works on these 10 seconds, I'll use the larger set.) Then I randomly chose a sample subset (with replacement) of N elements from the 45 stations for each second where 3 < N <=15. I chose the N elements randomly about 100 times each and calculated the average of all the 100 standard deviations. Then I looked for an N that had an average standard deviation value close to "the" answer for the 45 stations. As it turned out, when N=14 then the StdDev of the subsets closely matched "the" set.

I also looked at the area that those random samples enclosed (the convex hull) though results have been inconclusive. I calculated metrics such as 1) area enclosed 2) perimeter of convex hull 3) sensor density for area 4) sensor density for perimeter.

I'd just like to know if I'm on the right track here, or if there's a method that I don't know about that would be a good fit for this application.

Comment: Could you clarify what "maintaining the solar variability means"? If we cannot understand that clearly, then we might not appreciate what you are trying to accomplish.  When you make that edit, please fix your second paragraph, which appears to have become corrupted.  Also, because it is not apparent what your four metrics might have to do with this problem, anything you can add to address that would be welcome.

Comment: @whuber - thanks for the comments. I edited the original post per your suggestion. I hope it is more clear. The four metrics are related to maintaining the spatial smoothing of the variability. Consider a single point sensor that measures irradience. The recorded values on a partly cloudy day are variable. However, the average irradience value over a square mile would be less variable. The four metrics I calculate are quantifying the areas that the actual sensors represent - larger areas probably have more smoothing. The sensor density is just a clustering metric.